# How to fix an error in "map.getview().setcenter" of openlayers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, maps, openlayers, openstreetmap

I implement openlayers in .net mvc with C#. I try to center a map and in local its works but on the server get an error.

When I comment the line `map.getview().setcenter` the rest of the project works

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "GetCoordinateSibuc",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ clientId: $('#filterClientSelect').val(), sibucId: $('#filterSibuc').val() }),
        contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {

            map.getView().setCenter([response.longitud, response.latitud], 11);

            var sibucStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    anchor: [0.5, 5],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                    opacity: 1,
                    scale: 1,
                    src: '/Content/images/report/mark_sibuc1.png'
                }))
            });
```

I expect to get the map center in the coordinates but i get error in JS like:

> Script terminate by timeout.

And in the server log:

> perflib 1008
>
> perfnet 2004

Comment: Try logging the response in your JavaScript `console.log(response.longitud); console.log(response.latitud);` If that looks valid it might be a string when OpenLayers expects a number, so you may need to use `[Number(response.longitud), Number(response.latitud)]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method. The `map.setCenter()` get only one parameter that is center. So you might use this code:

```
map.getView().setCenter([response.longitud, response.latitud]);
```

For more information, you can check the Openlayers API [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#setCenter) about `setCenter()`.
Also, there is another method you can use instead of `setCenter()`. It has more option like zoom, center, etc. check [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#animate) for API. I think this is what you need:

```
map.getView().animate({center: [response.longitud, response.latitud]}, {zoom: 11});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In OpenLayers 2 there was an optional second parameter to set the zoom.  In OL3+ extra parameters would simply be ignored.  But on a new map the zoom would need to be pre-set for setCenter to work.

Comment: It is 5.2.0. we tried:

    map.getView().animate({center: [response.longitud, response.latitud]}, {zoom: 11});

 it works at the local proyect but in the IIS have the same errors

Comment: Try logging or look for errors in the browser console. more information could help.